# Ubuntu reboots when pressing the off button

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

So I have a slight problem, I've been using ubuntu 16.04 for a while, and lately, it reboots whenever I try to turn it off, I do this by pressing the off button, or even using the command to turn it off... what could be causing this?

Comment: 16.04 comes with Python 2.7.11 preinstalled. Why would you want 2.7.8 specifically?

Comment: I need 2.7.8 because it works really well with the arduino. I need python for a part. Also, In the video I'm watching they use python 2.7.8, so I don't want to mess around too much. Also I'll need to add libraries to 2.7.8 so I'm trying very hard to not mess up.

Comment: 2.7.8 and 2.7.11 differ only in the micro version number, so there are only very minor updates and bug fixes included. 2.7.11 can be expected to be fully downwards compatible with 2.7.8. You will surely not note any difference.

Comment: So all extra packages for 2.7.8 will work with 2.7.11?

Comment: Also, I have to be able to save it.

Comment: I can only find it in terminal.

Comment: You said you need the newly installed Python to be 32-bit. Is that to say that the installed system is 64-bit?

Comment: Yes, only the major (2) and sometimes also the minor (7) version number matters. The micro (8 or 11) just indicates small patches and bug fixes, but no additional or changed functionality. So all packages for 2.7 will work on any 2.7, but older versions like 2.7.8 might have had little bugs affecting those packages that might have got fixed in 2.7.11. It's definitely batter (and here also easier) to use 2.7.11 than 2.7.8. And what do you mean by "save it"? And by "only find it in terminal"?

Comment: Well when I look up 'python' or '2.7.11'  I see nothing in search your computer. When I go to terminal and type python, I get just a prompt but I can't save the file. Also, to answer Eliah Kagan's question yes I have 64 bit and need 32 bit because every package for python and the arduino works with 32 bit whilst not all packages work with 64bit. Using it for my arduino is what I'm using it for.

Comment: This edit is a totally new question unrelated to what was asked before about python. As a result all the previous comments are meaningless. If you have solved the old problem feel free to answer your old question. If the old question is not relevant any more please delete it. Ask a new question by pressing the **Ask Question** button.

Comment: It won't let me since I'm banned.